# Can I use a NStimer in another NStimer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I create a `NSTimer`:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(sendImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In the method `sendImage`, I create another `NSTimer` `timer2`. The code following:

```
- (void)sendImage
  {
     for(int i = 0;i < 50 ; i++)
     {
         NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
         [dict setObject:socket forKey:@"socket"];//parameter which deliver to the method`sendPieceOfImage`
         [dict setObject:pData forKey:@"pData"];
         timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.002f target:self selector:@selector(sendPieceOfImage:) userInfo:dict repeats:NO];
     }
  }
```

But it didn't work. I want to know can `NSTimer` apply mechanically? If it's infeasible, what can I do in the `sendImage`. I hope every cycle in the `for()` can run with interval.

Comment: "But it didn't work" - did it produce an error, blow up, fry an egg ;-), etc.? Detail will help people help you. Edit your question to add details and someone might be able to help.

Comment: Does the first timer work fine? Is `sendImage` method called?

Comment: You are re-creating the timer 50 times?  How is that supposed to work?

Comment: in validate timer 2 in for loop

Comment: @trojanfoe scheduled timer is retained by the runloop, so the 50 timers should work.

Comment: But why do you need them?  Would you use 50 timers each doing 1 thing or 1 timer doing 50 things? Why hold a reference to the (last created) timer in an instance variable?

Comment: @trojanfoe agree with you, that's strange. But from my perspective the question is why "mechanism" does not work, so "policy" of the "mechanism" usage does not matter for me. That's other question.

Comment: @CRD @Melifaro @trojanfoe @PKT  The problem is that the `timer` worked,the `timer2` did not work.The method `sendPieceOfImage:` cannot be called continuously,interval is needed,so I use `timer2`.

Comment: I believe you are attempting to solve some sort of concurrent network issue, and doing it badly.

Comment: @trojanfoe you are right,can you help me?I tried to add `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.002f]`,but it made the program  weird.

Comment: Get away from `NSTimer`.  What you are looking for is probably `NSOperationQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is YES. That's possible to schedule one timer in the firing callback of another. Consider this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timer1Event:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
});

- (void)timer1Event:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSLog(@"timer1Event");
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timer2Event:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)timer2Event:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSLog(@"timer2Event");
}
```

Even the problem is not fully described, I'll try to guess that the rootcause is in how very first timer is scheduled.

You need thread with aproprietaly setted up RunLoop. Main thread is suitable.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(sendImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
});
```

If you don't want to load the main thread, consider this:

You need your own thread:

```
self.workerThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startRunLoop) object:nil];
[self.workerThread start];
```

Which starts the runloop:

```
- (void)startRunLoop
{
    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    do {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2.0]];
        }
    } while (![NSThread currentThread].isCancelled);
}
```

Now, for starting the timer on the worker thread you need this:

```
- (void)startTimer
{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(timerEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

How to call:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startTimer) onThread:self.workerThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot,my friend...but it's not suit to my program.

Comment: Well @X.Rodi , probably I misunderstood your question. It looks like you are interested in "Async pice of image sending" instead of "Scheduling timer inside callback on another timer".

Comment: your answer did help me in another issue.Thanks again.